# Rails: How to specify valid values for fields in my model via another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

What I want to do is define a list of valid values, and then validate against that list of values, when adding a new role on a related table.

Let me provide a concrete example:

Say I have an 'Employment' table, with the following fields:

```
user_id (tied to a user table)
employer_id (tied to an employer table)
position_id (tied to a position table)
details
efbegdt
efenddt
```

When a user adds a new row to this table, I want to ensure that the employer_id and position_id already exist on the other tables, and to not permit the save if that's not the case in either instance.

The solutions I've seen so far take the form of this:

```
class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base
  EMPLOYERS = ['Google', 'Yahoo', 'Microsoft']
  POSITIONS = ['Web Developer', 'Database Admin', 'QA']
  validates_inclusion_of :employer_id, :in => EMPLOYERS
  validates_inclusion_of :position_id, :in => POSITIONS
end
```

But that approach is not flexible enough to accomodate potentially thousands of employers and positions, nor does it provide an easy way to allow users to add new valid entries, if their employer currently doesn't exist.

I've also seen this approach:

```
class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :employer_exists

  protected

  def employer_exists
    ids = Employer.all.map(&:id)
    if !employer_id.blank? && !ids.member?(employer_id)
      errors.add(:employer_id, "invalid employer")
    end
  end
end
```

This is closer to what I want, but when I test that with rspec, checking if a new row on the employer table is valid fails:

```
Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
  expected valid? to return true, got false
```

Is there a 'best practice' solution to this problem?

**UPDATE**

Just adding another example, with all the setup detailed.  In this example, users can have multiple email addresses stored on an email table, but there is a limit of one address per type (personal, work, school, etc).  Another table, email_dfn, defines all the valid types:

**migrate files**

```
class CreateEmailDfns < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :email_dfns do |t|
      t.string :short_description
      t.string :long_description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class CreateEmails < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :emails do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :email_dfn_id
      t.string :value
      t.text :notes

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :emails, [:user_id, :email_dfn_id]
  end
end
```

**Model**

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :value, :notes, :email_dfn_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :email_dfn

  validates_associated :email_dfn

  valid_email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :value, presence: true,
                    length: { maximum: 256 },
                    format: { with: valid_email_regex },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :email_dfn_id, presence: true
end
```

and

```
class EmailDfn < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :short_description,
                  :long_description,
  validates_uniqueness_of :short_description,
                          :long_description

  has_many :emails
end
```

**tests**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Email do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { @email = user.emails.build(email_dfn_id: 1,
                                      value: "personal_email@test.com",
                                      notes: "My personal email address") }

  subject { @email }

  it { should respond_to(:value) }
  it { should respond_to(:notes) }
  it { should respond_to(:email_dfn_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:user) }
  its(:user) { should == user }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when user id is not present" do
    before { @email.user_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email id is invalid" do
    before { @email.email_dfn_id = 999 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

In this current setup, the last test (setting email_dfn_id = 999, an invalid code) fails.

Answer (score 1):

Use `validate_associated`

```
class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee

  validates_associated :employee
end
```

Read the documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: I thought about doing this as well... the problem I hit with this approach is the following rspec test will fail:  

'describe "when employer_id is invalid" do  
  before { @employment.employer_id = 999 }  
  it { should_not be_valid }  
end'  

Where employer_id = 999 is currently not a valid ID on the employer table

Comment: You should pre-create an `Employer` before the test.

Comment: Yeah - I did this as well, though I didn't realize in some of my initial work, I had gotten the auto-incremented ID to a higher number than I thought.  After resetting the test database, I'm able to validate against the correct ID of 1 (see new example in main post), but this 'validates_associated' setup still seems insufficient to require validating that the ID is valid (ie, the test for ID = 999 still comes back 'valid', when it shouldn't)

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
validates :employer_id, presence: true, inclusion: { in: Employer.all.map(&:id), message: 'must be a valid employer.' }
```

Comment: Your solution can be expensive, when the `employees` table has 1000s of rows as you will loading all id's to memory and performing a array lookup for every validation. Apart from this, in production mode this solution will not include the employees added after starting the server.

Comment: I don't think it will be that expensive. I'm also not sure your second point is correct. I tried firing up my console in production mode, and ModelName.all did update when creating new records.

Comment: This does seem to work to require that the ID be valid, but I am concerned about scaling.  The other problem I hit with this approach is that the check that the new row is valid comes back as fail.  (See update to my post above...  it { should be_valid } is the one that will fail in this case)

Comment: The `Model.all` call doesn't capture the scenario I am referring to. The validation list gets initialized when the classes are loaded. Once initialized the list doesn't change. You can test this by trying to validate your code against a new row added to the database. If you want to recalculate the list for every validation, you have to supply a `lambda` instead of a static list.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. I do use lambdas for some of my validations when defining statics lists didn't work, but I had no idea why that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `user belongs_to employer` in your relationship setup.

In this case, maybe you could simplify the code using the association methods.

If you're using the default form builder,

```
<% f.select("user", "employer_id", Employer.all) %>
```

This gives you a select box with all the possible employers who are already defined. However, your user can still spoof the create and insert a new employer ID that does not exist. (sidenote: I don't know why they might do that).

As much as possible, I will recommend using the associated methods instead of writing custom validation functions etc because it makes your code easier to understand to other people.

If you just needed validation, the other answer is probably better =)

In your create action, you can do one more check.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:id])
  @user.employer = Employer.find(params[:user][:employer_id])

  ..... # Standard save code or your own. 

end
```

If it's more to do with authorization and security, you can consider implementing a gem like `cancan` to narrow down the universe of choices that a user can choose.

**For authorization and other permissions purpose**

For example, you don't want people to choose a 'disabled' / 'preview' entry. If you used cancan, you can have a method like this.

```
<% f.select("user", "employer_id", Employer.accessible_by(current_ability) %>
```

If their ability is properly defined, trying to spoof the system will end up with an access denied.

Comment: Good ideas here - but like you said as well, I really want to implement this via association methods if possible.  I've posted another (very specific) example in the main post - any thoughts on why this current setup isn't enforcing the requirement that the ID of the email be 'valid', as defined on the email_dfn model?